# Recreating a simple carousel slider from JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I am recreating this slide found on StackOverflow but with different tags as some of the names are used elsewhere in my site and conflict.

The original JS Fiddle can be found here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/KSHSX/6/

The JS Fiddle that I am trying to change to fit within my site can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/owenoneill/KzmTM/1/

I would like it to work as the first one but with different div names, and by using a tags instead, basically exactly the same but with different ids/classes - I'm usually okay at customising basic javascript/css attributes, but having a little trouble this time round.

Any help is appreciated, I feel like I'm  nearly there.

Separate MarkUp can be seen below:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sliderWidth = 300;
        var slider = $('#slidie');
        var sliderCount = $('div', slider).length;
        slider.width(sliderCount * sliderWidth);

        $('a.date-nav-prev').click(function () { 
            $('#slidie').animate({left: '+='+sliderWidth}, 500);
        });

        $('a.date-nav-next').click(function () {
            $('#slidie').animate({left: '-='+sliderWidth}, 500);
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<a class="date-nav-prev">< Prev</a>
<a class="date-nav-next">Next ></a>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slidie">
        <div id="daysAgo2">Actions from 2 Days Ago</div>
        <div id="yesterday">Yesterday's Actions</div>
        <div id="today">Today's Actions</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper{
        width:300px; 
        height:300px; 
        border:1px solid #333;
        position:relative; 
        overflow:hidden;
        }
        #slidie {
            width: 1000px !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #slidie div {
            width:300px; 
            height:100%; 
            float:left; 
        }
        #today{background:green;}
        #yesterday {background:yellow;}
        #daysAgo2 {background:orange;}
    </style>
```

Any thoughts, directions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/KzmTM/2/

Your fiddle is fine except for the style tag wrapping the css.
Get rid of

```
 <style type="text/css">
```

Update:  The reason it was working in the fiddle and not on his site was the javascript on his site wasn't wrapped in  `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I still cannot work it out, it's not working so they may be a jQuery conflict somewhere? Can you private message with a link or anything as I still cannot work out where it's not working :/

Comment: What isn't working? The fiddle in my answer behaves the same as your original fiddle for me.

Comment: The anchor tags are not moving anything across from left to right - the JS Fiddle works, but when added to the site, it doesn't work

Comment: let me know you when you have the details :)

Comment: I have it.  Which js file includes the slider?